# Como limitar decimales sin redondear

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual se encarga de limitar el numero de decimales del resultado

```
a = 14567
n = "%.1f" % (a/1000)+"K")
```

al momento de hacer in `print()`, me da como resultado `14.6K,` el problema es que yo no quiero que me lo redonde, ya he intentado con la funcion round, pero me da el mismo resultado.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Qué deseas que muestre?

Comment: los decimales correpondientes 14.5.

Comment: 14.5 no es igual a 14.567. Como número siempre lo va a redondear al truncar; como cadena puede que obtengas lo que buscas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde el formato, entiendo que no hay forma, siempre va a redondear a la cantidad de decimales que definas. Lo que en general se sugiere es armar una rutina para "truncar" directamente la cantidad de decimales que quieras:

```
import math

def trunc(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

a = 14567
n = "%.1f" % trunc(a/1000,1) +"K"

print(n)

14.5K
```

Sino la otra forma es cortar directamente el número ya convertido en una cadena

```
n = str(a/1000)
print(n[:n.index('.')+2] + "K")
14.5K
```

Answer (score 2):

El formateador `%.1f` usa `round()` para limitar el número de decimales a la cantidad que le pidas. Esta función admite un flotante (a redondear) y un entero (número de decimales a preservar). Así, básicamente, hará `round(x, 1)` en este caso.

`round()` usa como regla para redondeo la de tomar el número más cercano, con el número de decimales solicitado. En tu caso, ya que la operación `a/1000` resulta en `14.567`, hay que elegir como resultado del redondeo `14.5` o `14.6`. El más cercano al verdadero valor es `14.6` y esa es por tanto la respuesta.

<sub>**Digresión** En caso de que ambos estén a igual distancia (por ejemplo `14.550` está a igual distancia de `14.5` que de `14.6`) python usa una extraña regla consistente en redondear hacia el que tenga el dígito **par**. En este ejemplo entonces redondearía hacia `14.6`, es decir, hacia arriba. Pero siguiendo esa misma regla resulta que `14.650` *también* redondearía hacia `14.6`, es decir *hacia abajo*. Este extraño comportamiento es poco conocido, pero es correcto pues está siguiendo un estándar llamado *round half to even*, parte del IEEE-754. No obstante otros lenguajes no lo hacen así, hay que estar sobreaviso.</sub>

Volviendo a tu pregunta, aunque es un poco raro lo que pides, la forma más flexible de trabajar con redondeos es hacer uso del paquete `decimal`. Este paquete evita además errores adicionales que pueden producirse al operar con coma flotante, ya que en coma flotante los números se almacenan en binario, y cuando divides por 10 o potencias de 10 (como suele ser habitual en el sistema métrico decimal, o en finanzas), ya que 10 no es potencia de 2, eso produce errores.

Por ejemplo, tu operación 14567/1000 no produce en realidad 14.567 como dije antes, sino 14.567000000000000170530256582424. Lo que pasa es que normalmente no se muestran tantos decimales.

Usando el módulo `decimal` la sintaxis se vuelve muy farragosa, pero aseguras que los decimales y los redondeos se hacen correctamente:

```
import decimal
a = Decimal(14567)
n = "%sK" % (a/1000).quantize(Decimal('1.1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
print(n)
```

```
14.5K
```